# Which file to change this code...?

Tags: wordpress

I embedded some code for a mailchimp form on a post on my wordpress blog.

I signed up to the list to test it, but the form signed me up to a different list in my mailchimp account.

It's the form in the main section on this page: http://wordfruit.com/blog/fish-and-the-blackbird/

I want the form to enable people to sign up to a list with the title 'Publications Updates'. Instead, it's signing people up to the list 'How to Write to Persuade and Sell', which is a list connected to a form in the sidebar of the site.

Mailchimp told me this: "it looks like (as you mentioned) you're embedding the correct code, but at the bottom of your website there is some script that is overriding what you're doing when you embed the form. Specifically, there is a section at the veeery bottom of your page's source code that has a reference to the "How to Write to Persuade and Sell" list. This screenshot shows the section I'm referring to: http://screencast.com/t/rbw44HzeY - What I'd suggest doing would be to go into your site's code and replacing the section in that screenshot with this ID: 827164e224.

My questions:

1. I can't find the file with the source code the mailchimp guy mentioned. What would likely be the name of the file?
2. Any idea how that code could've got there? I only added the 'How to Write to Persuade and Sell' signup form into the sidebar...

Comment: First you need to find the correct file. Are you working on Windows or Linux? On Windows you should enter the Windows Search in the wordpress folder an search for : '6040bdc940e837429ec457e49'. When on Linux cd to the project folder and post the output of `grep -rn 6040bdc940e837429ec457e49 .`

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this js file is inside /blog/fish-and-the-blackbird.js or similar.